# How to make custom tableview that works with searchbar and design

Tags: ios, uitableview, tableview, uisearchbar

Im stuck on this problem.

im trying to make a design like this."[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0S3zo.png)"

i want it to work with searchbar and a filter/sorter.

I can't find out how to make a tableview with individual views horizontal and vertical.
Is it posible to make a custom tableview like this, that works with the searchbar?

Thanks.

Comment: SO is not a free coding service. Give it a try and come back with specific questions related to problems you encounter.

Comment: Sorry, just trying to learn, needed a place to start.

Answer (score 0):

You should use a `UICollectionView` instead.
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uicollectionview

Comment: Thnku, this was what i was looking for!